# find files from a list of files and perform deletion

Tags: command-line, find

I want to find many file names which are written in a text file. How could I pass this text file to the `find` command (or another command?) to find every line of it (every line is a file name)? My aim is to find all file names and delete them.

```
find /path/to/my/files -name "list-from-file.txt" -delete
```

Comment: Add example input, please.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Add example snippets with details of what you are planning to do here.

Comment: `find` command searches for files but you want to search for file _contents_ if I understand correctly. `grep` would be a better tool for that.

Comment: … or `sed` or `awk` if you want to modify file contents in the same run – we need much more information and some lines of example text to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a file (let’s call it `filenames.txt`) with the list of file names you want to delete, e.g.

```
a.txt
subfolder1/b.sh
subfolder2/subfolder3/c.jpg
/home/user/a.txt
```

you just need to `cd` to the folder where the relative paths contained in the file are valid and issue the command:

```
< path/to/filenames.txt xargs echo rm
```

You’ll notice this will just list the `rm` commands. This is a security check. Remove `echo` to fire the file removal at your own risk!

Notice the paths will be directly passed to `rm` with no additional measures, so the last line in my example will work as an absolute path.

Comment: @Melebius OP mentioned the list is only contains _files name_ and based on his find pseudo code passing to `-name` parameter. BTW he accepted this answer!

Comment: @AFSHIN Well, since OP gave no example, I implemented the simplest option and expected a few iterations. I upvoted your answer which looks correct to me.

Answer (score 4):

Use `find` with `xargs` if you have only files name saved in myTextFile:

```
xargs -d '\n' -a /path/to/myTextFile -I FILENAME find /src -type f -name FILENAME #-delete
```

if you know all files are in one specific directory or they have their *path* included, then the command would be:

```
xargs -d '\n' -a /path/to/myTextFile echo rm -f --
```

Or using simple `bash` script.

```bsh
while IFS='\n' read -r FILE
do
    find /src -type f -name "$FILE" #-delete
done < /path/to/myTextFile
```

Answer (score 2):

Push your myTextFile to a while loop with `read` command:

```sh
while IFS= read -r f; do
   test -f "$f" && rm -f "$f"
done < myTextFile
```

Comment: Why test for existence and file type right before (forceful) deletion?

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in `less list-from-file.txt`; do rm $i;done
```

where `less` will open the file `list-from-file.txt`

So, each line of the file `list-from-file.txt` is in `$i`

Finally, `rm` command will remove the file.

Comment: my answer that I posted is not showing the character (`) for less command. Sorry

Comment: pleae check my edit, is that what you wanted? If not please correct as you want ... good luck!

Comment: -1 for [useless use of backticks](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks) and lack of proper escaping. See [Rovo’s answer](/a/950849/175814) for a good implementation of a similar approach.